# Is it possible to share session between different PHP versions?

Tags: php, apache, symfony, session, iis

I am starting an old app refactoring, I will rebuild some functionality from spaghetti code to MVC (Symfony). Plan was I will set up new IIS app, using subdomain. Now, old app is running PHP 5.3 which can't be upgraded. New app will be running on PHP 5.6. Only thing I need to carry is authentication. I can have login script either on old or new app.
I tried setting session cookie params but I can't get it working.

Is it possible at all or do I have to use database?
If it is not possible, can that be achieved in Apache?

**Edit:**

What I'm to do is:

```
session.cookie_domain = ".dev"
```

In both php.ini. Then I start the session in one, set a session variable.

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['test'] = 123;
```

Then in the second app (php 5.6) I'm trying to read it:

```
session_start();
var_dump($_SESSION);
```

But it's empty.

Comment: the session is in default stored in a file. The may be a little chance that both php versions can use the same files. But i don't know exactly.

Comment: session cookie works fine in both version. need more information? show what code you have tired?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently setting session cookie domains does not work for top level domains (TLD), like .dev

Changed my code to:

```
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.local.dev');
```

and now I am able to set session variables on .local.dev website and read them in new.local.dev

Both apps are physically in separate folders, operate from two IIS entries and using different PHP versions.

Answer (score 0):

For sharing session between different php versions, they have to physically have the same [session.save_path ini setting](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-path) which defaults to `/tmp`.

So if you have two PHP versions in different Docker containers, you should set the `session.save_path` for both versions to something like `/tmp/php_session` and then share that directory with both Docker containers.